# Ruby iterators -- get next item/items

Tags: ruby, iterator, idioms

In parsing a file, I want to look for a line and then start parsing there:

```
inFile.each_line do |line|
    if line == 'User E'
        #start parsing next line
    end
end
```

How do you recommend I do this sort of thing? Should I just go back to normal loops? If I use `break`, is there any way to keep the iteration count from the iterator?

Comment: How big is the file?  You could use a few other methods that read the contents into an array and you can abuse this to search then.

Comment: @squiguy There are just a few hundred lines (less than 300), most of which are over 10,000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
string = "I want to parse from here to here"
index = string.index(from)
string[index,-1].each_line do |l|
  parse
end
```

This way should be faster than using split or adding a test for each line.

If your file is big, you might want to get it in chunks.